# Ocean's 13 roulette dialog meaning

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-thirteen

I was watching *Ocean's 13* there is a line before the mass winning scene and where GRECO goes down and I don't understand what it means.

This is where Yen is disguised as a wealthy overseas businessman(?) and places 10 million on roulette.

Willy is downstairs at the GRECO command center checking out if the earthquake knocked out the system and a pit boss is trying to get clearance on the 10 million bet.

Willy allows it and the pit boss gives a nod to the roulette employee. Then he says

> All right, the gentleman's down to a three-number combination. 11, 12 and 13.

And then the ball drops onto 13.

What does this mean? I do know it pays homage to the movies but is that really what this line is for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 3 number combination means he's betting that the ball will land on on **any one of those numbers**.

[image]

The payout *if it hits* is 11 to 1 which means he's just won **110 million dollars**.

It's a little odd as these type of bets are usually done on "streets" which represent the rows on the table but there's no reason a 3-number combo wouldn't be accepted for row numbers....especially with the approval of the pit-boss.

Comment: Oh that is interesting. I'm guessing the employee is just saying that out loud for out of protocol for a high bet. Still seems like an odd line.

Comment: Those 3 numbers are, of course, the 3 numbers of the Oceans movies. It's a cute self-reference (I think).

Comment: That's referenced in the question....

Comment: where would you put your chips on the above image to get and 11, 12, 13 combination?

Comment: On those numbers but you'd have to make sure that the croupier was aware...which he obviously is. Normally they are placed on the edge of the row (AFAIK) but these aren't on a row together.